# nginx map w/ server directive. Forward http -> https

Tags: nginx

I have 7 services.  I'd like them to automatically forward http->https.

I'm trying this, but it's not working:

```
map $http_host $backend {
  apples.example.com        http://127.0.0.1:3006;
  oranges.example.com       http://127.0.0.1:3000;
  bananas.example.com       http://127.0.0.1:3010;
  pears.example.com         http://127.0.0.1:3012;
  dragonfruit.example.com   http://127.0.0.1:3014;
  peaches.example.com       http://127.0.0.1:3002;
  tomatos.example.com       http://127.0.0.1:3016;
}


# All services (except button) forward HTTP -> HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    return 307 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
```

I'm misunderstanding something because one of the services isn't matching up.

`http://apples.example.com` is forwarding to `https://peaches.example.com`

I'm running this to test:

```
sudo service nginx restart && wget http://apples.example.com/ --no-check-certificate
```

And it's returning:

```
--2016-10-05 20:07:37--  http://apples.example.com/
Resolving expert-dev.bigsmall.io (apples.example.com)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to expert-dev.bigsmall.io (apples.example.com)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://peaches.example.com [following]
--2016-10-05 20:07:37--  https://peaches.example.com/
```

nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Any suggestions?

Comment: server_name could not contain variable. Also you've missed semicolon. Please, show real complete config

Comment: @AlexeyTen Hmmm...  Ok, the first version had no server_name (updated question).  I added server_name and it still didn't work.  Is this even the right approach?